# Make window manager cover whole screen

Tags: android

can I somehow do my `windowmanger` cover whole screen with status bar and then to make it untouchable? If yes, please give an example of doing so. I've tried `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` with `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` and `FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE` but this didn't disable status bar area, and I just think so but may be `FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE` didn't even disable touch events. Because I don't know why but sometimes some flags do not work in my apps.

Comment: If you want to set status bar not visible, you can set Fullscreen. Did you mean this? <activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>

Comment: @stanley-kou No, I want to hide status bar in windowmanager, not in activity